# iOS XMPPFramework - Find resource of JID from presence, but presence not being received/sent?

Tags: android, ios, xmpp, xmppframework, user-presence

I am creating a chat app on iOS using the XMPPFramework and finding an issue with `sending and receiving friend requests`.

I find that I need to find/get a resource when creating a JID on `XMPPFramework`. But whenever I send or receive a friend request between Android and iOS, those requests are not being received.

So I came to the conclusion that the resource part of the JID plays an important role in sending the request to the actual device that is being used. The resource acts like one single connection between XMPP server and device. Android is using "Smack" as resource part of JID internally, and iOS uses, well, whatever I want, iPhone, in this case.

How do I get this resource part of the JID from a user? I have seen questions being posted on how to find resource and the answer is to read the presence received from the sender of the request. But I don't receive any presence from Android devices until I forcefully add resource for the user while sending request.

Also does this have something to do with `priority` of presence?